# Is this space metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we introduce a topology on $\mathbb R$: A subset $N$ of $\mathbb R$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ if $x \in N$ and $N^c$ is finite. Can we introduce some metric on this space such that the topology is preserved? I'd appreciate some pointers, but try not to state any known theorem, since I just started learning topology, and am not familiar with the well known results in the area. Thanks and merry christmas!

Comment: If you want to read mroe about this topology, search for the 'cofinite' topology or the 'Zariski' topology. They are important in algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the space is metrizable, it needs to be Hausdorff, which it is not.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: show that this topology is not Hausdorff.